# Removable drive connected over OTG disconnects when screen turns off

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I own a tablet with Jelly Bean installed. I usually connect a pen drive to it using an OTG cable and it works fine (except for NTFS file system and the below problem too). The issue is when the screen turns off after the time out while the storage device is connected, it disconnects itself. If I turn the screen on, it will be mounted automatically.

It is annoying to change the time-out now-and-then and keeping it on for a long time by touching the display.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any option in Settings (maybe Settings->Storage) to keep OTG connected in sleep mode.

If you don't find anything related to that, it means there's some bug with the ROM.

Maybe you can try this app: [USB Autosleeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.as.powerchecker&hl=en)

This app doesn't allow the phone to sleep when USB is connected.
Whenever you connect OTG, run that app and do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

There might be an option to change that in Settings. If you can't find it, look in Developer Settings. If you don't have that, go to About Phone and tap 7 times on build number.

Comment: It'd be better if you could be more specific on what settings the OP should find. Also, I couldn't find anything like that on "Developer options". I found "Stay awake", but that only prevents the screen from turning off while charging instead of connected to USB OTG.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't able to find the setting for it through your system UI, you can also try finding it through [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22).

Comment: While recommending an app to solve an issue is acceptable, this answer still lacks details on how it solves the issue (particularly what setting should be edited).

Comment: Hi @Andrew T., thank you for your advice, I can certainly understand what you mean.  In this particular case, I thought to contribute this application because it offers a means to directly access and edit various device .db settings files.  However, 1) more specific instructions would require more details such as the device specs and whether they have root access or not, etc.  2) Without such details, it's also uncertain whether the other answers already provided by others are sufficient to solve the issue.  In this case, would it have been better etiquette to post as a comment to OP instead?